# Returning tag value for a key path from a json using dpath.util or anything else

Tags: python, json, data-transform, dpath

I have this json :

```
 json_data = json.loads("""
{
    "result":{         
        "statistics": [
                        {
                            "name": "A1",
                            "year": 1994,
                            "award": "Y1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "X1",
                            "year": 1990,
                            "award": "Y55"
                        }
                    ]
            }
}""")
```

I'm trying to get all the values for every occurance of "name" in the json for a key path using dpath.util.get

```
print(dpath.util.get(json_data, 'result/statistics/name', separator= '/'))
```

I'm getting this error after running :

```
        raise KeyError(glob)
KeyError: 'result/statistics/name'
```

> Expected result:
>
> ```
> {'name' : '['A1','X1']'}
> ```

I'm trying to do it like this because the json can change and that path is always relevant for a specific json.
I have no problem with other solutions also.

Comment: Recommend you to go throught the doc one, https://pypi.org/project/dpath/

Comment: I did, have I missed anything, from what I understand the get is what suits my needs compared with the rest of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

### Quick Answer (TL;DR)

- JMespath allows for querying arbitrary JSON-based data structures in python 3.x
- python dpath may not always work, because JSON-based data can contain both dictionary (aka object) and list types
- standard python is sufficient to obtain the desired result

### Detailed Answer

#### Context

- python 3.x
- query and transform arbitrary JSON data structure

#### Problem

- **Scenario:** UserJerryC wishes to query a JSON data structure using python `dpath`

  - `dpath` produces an error message when attempting the query
  - UserJerryC is willing to use other solutions besides `dpath`
  - it is assumed UserJerryC has a reason for not using standard python functionality to access the data

#### Solution

- use JMespath to query and transform arbitrary JSON-based data structure
- python `dpath` library works with dictionary-based data structures, but JSON can contain more than just dictionaries (aka objects, aka mappings, aka associative-arrays)

#### Example

- python 3.6 code demonstrating a JMespath query

  ```
    import json
    import jmespath
    pass
    json_data = json.loads("""
    {
      "result": {
        "statistics": [
          {
            "award": "Y1",
            "name": "A1",
            "year": 1994
          },
          {
            "award": "Y55",
            "name": "X1",
            "year": 1990
          }
        ]
      }
    }""")
    pass
    myquery     = """result.statistics|[*].name"""
    vg77result  = jmespath.compile(myquery).search(json_data)
    print(vg77result)         ## => ['A1', 'X1']
    pass
  ```

  > ['A1', 'X1']

#### Pitfalls

- this approach requires installing the python `jmespath` module which, like `dpath`, is not part of core python 3.x
- this result is possible without using `dpath` or `jmespath` through standard python

  ```
    """NOTE -- the above result could also be obtained with standard python"""
    vg99result  = [ row.get('name') for row in json_data['result']['statistics'] ]
    print(vg99result)         ## => ['A1', 'X1']
    pass
  ```

  > ['A1', 'X1']

#### See also

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dpath
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jmespath